# Is it possible to execute coded UI tests recorded with DevExpress "Universal" licencse in MSTest?

Tags: devexpress, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I got the following Question,

**Background:**
im using devexpress's **dxperience** license and i want to **record some coded ui tests**. the problem is i cant record devexpress controls with the dxperience license. Its only supported in devexpress's **univsersal** license.

But before im going to buy such a licence i asked me the following question. **Can i execute coded ui tests recorded under devexpress's Universal license in an other machine using MSTest in MS Visual Studio?** or does this machine needs this devexpress license(universal) too?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or does this machine needs this devexpress license(universal) too?

Yes:

[Coded UI Test Extension FAQ](http://www.devexpress.com/kbid=KA18720)

I suggest that you contact [DevExpress Support Team](http://www.devexpress.com/sc) to get an official response.